# ExtJs, keep an image from stretching in Ext.Img

Tags: javascript, html, image, extjs, extjs4

I am not sure if this can be done, but is it possible in ExtJS, in an `Ext.Img` component to keep the image from stretching to the size of the component and instead have it keep its proportions? To keep it from looking stretched?

Let me try to clarify this a bit from researching this, if in HTML I do something like this

```
<img src=# />
```

The image is not altered and is just the size I need it to be, if in ExtJs I do something like this

```
    xtype:'image',
    id: 'south_image',
    src: '#',
    region: 'south',
    width: 700,
    height: 200
```

Then the image turns out to be stretched, is there a way, assuming that `Ext.Img` is larger than the image, how do I get the image to keep its natural size like in HTML?

Comment: did you create image without specifying height and width?

Comment: The image can be uploaded by the user, I shrink it a little so it doesn't take too much space in the database. As I mentioned above, using the HTML `<img>` tag without specifying `width` or `height` works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I was able to find the answer, I had to put the `Ext.Img` inside of an `Ext.container.Container`, the size would be specified inside the container, while the size of the `Ext.Img` would be left blank:

```
    xtype: 'container',
    region: 'south',
    width: 700,
    height: 200,
    autoScroll: true,
    items: [{
        xtype:'image',
        id: 'south_image',
        src: '#',
        region: 'south',
        autoScroll: true
    }]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. Set the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` of the `Ext.Img`

Doc [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-maxHeight)

Comment: I don't see any difference, also not sure how `maxHeight` is different from `height`.

Comment: `height` is the size that is used while rendering the component. `maxHeight` is for setting it's maximum height if you're resizing the component say by increasing the width of the window. But you're right, you'll probably ned to set both `height` and `maxheight` and similarly for the widths.

Comment: Ok, I got it work, but then the image is still stretched to the `maxWidth` or `maxHeight`, how do I get the image to keep its natural size, like if I just used HTML `<img>` tag without specifying width or height?

Comment: Why not simply use an HTML `<img>` tag instead? You can use a `Ext.container.Container` with the `html` config option. Will that work for you?

Comment: I added the answer I found which is similar to what you mentioned. I don't think simply using the HTML tag wouldn't work since I have to modify the image source dynamically, unless I wanted to include JQuery to do that as well. But the method I mention works.